# ExtJS 4 Beta 3 Model Won't Load Data From JSON File

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

The model:

```
Ext.ns('Workout.Models.user');
Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: [{
        name: 'member_id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'first_name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'last_name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'username',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'password',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'dob',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
    }, {
        name: 'email_address',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'is_active',
        type: 'int'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        format: 'json',
        url: '../../_dev/json_fixtures/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        },
        root: 'users'
    }
});
```

The Store:

```
Ext.ns('Workout.Stores');
Workout.Stores.user = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'User',
    storeId : 'Workout.Stores.user',
    sorters: [
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'member_id'
    ],
    autoLoad: true
});
```

The Grid:

```
Ext.ns('Workout.User');
Workout.User.grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
    store: 'Workout.Stores.user',
    columns:[{
        text: 'Created At',
        dataIndex: 'created_at'
    }, {
        text: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'first_name'
    }]
});
```

The JSON File

```
{
    "users":[{
        "created_at":"2011-04-01 14:13:34",
        "member_id":"14453",
        "first_name":"Jemima",
        "last_name":"Petersen",
        "username":"jpeterson",
        "password":"TDW29HOH7WY",
        "dob":"1960-07-03",
        "email_address":"at.velit.Pellentesque@sociis.com"
    }]
}
```

Wheh I load my HTML page, the grid is empty. However, if I supply raw data to the store via the `data` param, it loads. If I call `User.load()` manually via the console, nothing happens. If i call `User.load()` and pass in a valid JSON object,nothing happens.

Is there something I'm missing / not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done everything expect set the height of your grid panel. You need to set the height to display the records. Here is what I would add to your grid panel config:

```
height: 300
```

Now, apart from this, you have other problems like you have not defined `created_at` in your User model. If you plan to display the value in your grid, you need to update your model as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! +1 and the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define(
'BK.store.Categories'
,   {       extend      :   'Ext.data.Store'
        ,   model       :   'BK.model.Category' 
        ,   autoload    :   true
        ,   proxy       :   {       type    :   'ajax'
                                ,   format  :   'json'
                                ,   root    :   'results'
                                ,   api     :   {   read    :   'data/data1.json'   }

                                ,   reader  :   new Ext.data.JsonReader({       type            :   'json'
                                                    ,   root            :   'results'
                                                    ,   successProperty :   'success'
                                                    })
                            }
    }
```

);

when I use data hardcoded in the store, it works OK (so model, view, controller are OK), as soon as I use the proxy it behaves as if autoload were FALSE, no net request